# failed to show image on kml description with php (yii 1)

Tags: php, yii

i want to generate kml file using yii, the problem is, i want to add an image on snippet description using html tag  but when it was generated, the image not show (broken), when i check the path, it works. why it happen? is kml description just support for text only? how i can add a picture on my snippet?

here is a screenshot :

[image]

thankyou in advance,

Comment: show a sample piece of the kml with image  ..

Comment: update your question adding a small part of kml where you code the img

Comment: if (!empty($ps->fotogedung)) $description .= '<br>'.ImageDisplayer::displaySmallFoto(RepositoryProfil::getRepoProfil($id_ps_periode),$ps->fotogedung,true);

Comment: is kml description doesn't support html image tag? <img> </img>

Comment: KML description support all tag ... but you show the php code for rendering the kml  .. i want see the kml result so i can check if is the right resulting code .. and please don't post code in comment ..but add the updating question ..